# We ought to be able to deny. But what?

Tags: sentence-construction

> This reflects deep tensions within the secular variant of the
>   workmanship ideal itself: **it presses relentlessly toward a kind of
>   moral determinism that its very terms suggest we ought to be able to
>   deny**
>
> The Moral Foundations of Politics by Ian Shapiro.

My question is about the word **deny**. What we ought to be able to deny?
Does author mean this some way?

Answer (score 1):

**"Moral determinism"**

The clause "its very terms suggest" is describing **why** or **how** we ought to be able to deny, but it could be omitted and the sentence would still make sense:

"it presses...toward...moral determinism that...we ought to be able to deny"